Creating a table in BigQuery with mixed data types
I have a table in BigQuery I'm trying to create in BigQuery that looks as such:



state
action_date




Alabama
None


Alaska
10/21/24


Delaware
10/28/24


District of Columbia
10/25/24


Florida
10/26/24


Louisiana
11/22/24


Maine
Varies



You will notice that the action_date field has a mix of DATE and STRING. Is there a way I can create a table where the schema is DATE despite the existence of those STRING values, which ideally would be retained?

In simple terms, no.
You could set a flag in a new field of “single”, “varies” or “none”, depending on the date value.
The action_date field would be populated with either a date value or NULL, and the string value would appear in the new field, which let’s call “activity”.
If activity = “single” then a date is placed in the action_date field.
If there is more than 1 activity date (wherever that comes from), then set activity = “varies”.
TLDR: No what you want is not possible if you want the field to be a datatype of date.
